# irritating garbage collector while processing audio ANDROID

Tags: java, android, audio, garbage-collection

i'm working on beat sequencer / mobile music studio. After spending about whole 2 weeks on this i'm almost decided to go native/ndk because of java/android generating junk on its own. But thought that doesn't hurt to ask before remaking whole project.

I need to generate audio buffer from sequence chunks as fast as possible. Now GC comes in and pauses my program for XXms, can't fill audio buffer, can't do nothing. Is there a way to avoid that? It's not my code which is generating that junk on heap (almost certain, because i commented out whole processing code leaving program clean as project template is).

I'm running that clean android project with one thread to monit heap free memory which is constantly dropping until it reaches point when GC pauses whole program. All the thread does is here:

```
    while(!done){
     Log.w("mem", ""+runtime.freeMemory());
     sleep(100);
    }
```

Why? Is it intended? It's important because it looks to me that i can do nothing to stop GC from executing. Also i can't use

```
System.gc()
```

anywhere after start processing because of i'm doing it on the fly.

Edit: Also is there a way to force android to give me more heap space? It's giving me 10 meg with 9.2 shared android stuff and 0.8 free.

Comment: Why do you think it's GC?

Comment: i think it's this: 10-06 20:17:11.203    5743-5766/pl.zgondek.sequencer D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 6% free 9375K/9920K, paused 16ms, total 16ms. But seriously. I know it's doing what it supposed to do, but there shouldn't be any work for him in first place